# css display property when a float is applied

Tags: css, css-float

When an element is floated, how do different display properties affect the layout? Or, what are the differences, if any, between these classes:

```
div.foo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

div.foo2 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

div.foo3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If there are no differences according to the spec, then do certain antiquated versions of browsers (ahem, IE) render them differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position) correctly, and practice confirms this,  setting `float: left` or `right` overrides the `display` property anyway and forces `display: block` on the element (although with peculiarities, see below), so there will no difference between your three examples:

> **left**
> The element generates a block box that is floated to the left. Content flows on the right side of the box, starting at the top (subject to the 'clear' property).
>
> **right**
> Similar to 'left', except the box is floated to the right, and content flows on the left side of the box, starting at the top.
>
> **none**
> The box is not floated.

Differently from normal `display: block` though, setting `float` dictates its own behaviour in regards to width that override the `display` property: if no width was explicitly specified, the floated element will take up as much width as it needs, as opposed to standard block element behaviour of taking up 100% width automatically.

Comment: That’s correct.  Floated elements always generate block boxes, regardless of any other CSS.  (The same is true of absolutely positioned elements.)