# I have set a background color to a div, but it disappears when I reduce the window size

Tags: css, background, width

The web page is ***[site link](http://lospardillos.com/)***. If you **reduce the window size**, the **transparent** grey `background` disappears. I have tried a number of things to fix this, without success. Any ideas?
CSS I've used is:

```
  #content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi now define  to `float:left;`  in your `#content id`

as like this

```
   #content{
    float:left;
    }
```

### --------------

**or** define

```
#content{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS rule that is only applied when the width is less than 980px which is adding a `float:left`. This is causing the background to disappear.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) .grid, .grid-right {
    float:none;
}
```

When the window is larger than 980px, `#content` has a computed style of

```
float:left;
display:block;
width: <not auto but some real px value>;
```

comprised from the following rules

```
.grid {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.127659574468%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.col-860 {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2.127659574468%;
}
```

Having `float:left` overrides `display:inline` and therefore `#content` becomes a block level element (see [css display property when a float is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774282/css-display-property-when-a-float-is-applied)) and the background color will be applied.

However, when the window is smaller than 980px, `#content` has a computed style of

```
float:none;
display:inline;
width:auto;
```

therefore `#content` is `display:inline` and the background will not appear - see [Why is my background color not showing if I have display: inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439820/why-is-my-background-color-not-showing-if-i-have-display-inline)

Removing the `@media screen and (max-width: 980px) .grid, .grid-right` rule will fix the problem but I assume this exists as part of the *responsive* site that scales and fits content to multiple resolutions and window sizes. I would recommend checking what behaviour is required at lower resolutions. Either way, giving `#content` a `display:block` or `float:left` in the case where the window is less than 980px will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
.grid{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* ... */
}
```

too. (removed float:left)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `display:table` to section, whole section.
For example, I have a div with 3 articles. I give a clearfix class to my div. Then I put `display:table` for div. The code is here:

```
<div class="clearfix">
<article></article>
<article></article>
<article></article>
</div>
.clearfix::after, .clearfix::before{ 
content: "";
clear: both;
display: table;
}
```