# CSS simple thumbnail grid shows weird spacing

Tags: css, grid-layout

I want to create a simple thumbnail grid for showing images from the [Europeana API](http://labs.europeana.eu/api). However for some weird, probably very obvious, reason I get random rows in this grid with large spaces as if the floating isn't working. However the same layout with random images (http://placehold.it/250x350) does not seem to have this problem. See result of html and css here: http://jsfiddle.net/VqJzK/1/ .

CSS of the grid

```
    .thumb {
        width: 200px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }

    .thumb img {
        width: 150px;
        vertical-align: middle;


    }​
```

and the html:

```
    <div class="thumb">
     <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_26_19311105%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
    </div>

    <div class="thumb">
     <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_02_19310521%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
    </div> 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken formatting is because some images are taller in the second example. The taller images take up more space and because the thumbnails have `float:left` set, they flow around the taller one. This explains why the first example works, since they all have the *same* height.

That said, `float:left` is also overriding the `display:inline-block` with `display:block` - see [css display property when a float is applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774282/css-display-property-when-a-float-is-applied)

If you remove `float:left` or set the height of the `.thumb` class the thumbnails will also line up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the standard `inline-block` bug, simple fix is to change your code to this:

```
 <div class="thumb">
     <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_26_19311105%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
    </div><div class="thumb">
     <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_02_19310521%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
    </div>
```

butt the elements right up next to each other, because it's treated as `inline` spaces between elements matter, because text itself is `inline`

alternatively you could use comments like this:

```
<div class="thumb">
         <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_26_19311105%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
</div><!--

--><div class="thumb">
         <img alt="test" src="http://europeanastatic.eu/api/image?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhdl.handle.net%2F10796%2FKOEKOEK_JG1_02_19310521%3Flocatt%3Dview%3Aderivative2&amp;size=LARGE&amp;type=TEXT"/>
   </div>
```